# Is there a noun that is like "law" except that it cannot, under any circumstances ever, be broken?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

Like the title says, I'm just wondering if there is a noun whose meaning is similar to that of a law, except that it necessarily can never be broken, undermined, or in any way skirted.

The closest I've come up with is "immutable" but that's an adjective, and I was hoping for a noun.  Everything else that I've come up with seems closer to vague approximations that are divine in nature, like "infinite." Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that there are no exceptions to the law's enforcement, or that it is impossible to violate the law? The law of gravity, for instance, is impossible to violate, but it requires no enforcement body.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Actually, every body in the universe enforces it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Perhaps we could say that those kinds of laws (like gravity) are "natural laws". (It always seemed to me unfair to poor old Archimedes that his law only got called a "principle". But it is every bit as immutable as the law of gravity - to which it is related.) I am trying to think of a generic term for a "civil" or "criminal" law. But I certainly can't think of one which "cannot be broken".

Comment: If you need to forbid people from doing it, they are capable of doing it. Then there are Grice's Maxims, known mostly by their various breaches. And the Laws of Large Numbers, while we're at it.

Comment: Laws are written so that someone can grant exceptions for a fee. If there is no fee to be had, what would be the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *absolute* may fit your specification.

Among its many (about a dozen) definitions I select

> 3. having no restriction, exception, or qualification.
>    “an absolute requirement”
>    and
> 4. : Positive, unquestionable
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absolute)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a noun for you, but,

> The closest I've come up with is "immutable" but that's an adjective,

I'd go with *inviolable*, meaning a law that can't be violated.

*Immutable* means the law never changes, but doesn't have the implication you asked for of a law that can't be broken.